# Unable to write PS output to file

Tags: powershell

I am running the following PS script but I cannot seem to write the output to a file

```
foreach ($user in get-content file.txt) { dsget user $user -samid } >> output_file.txt.
```

Results appear on screen just fine.  Is there something I am missing here?  Thanks!

Comment: Your redirection should be _inside_ the scriptblock, not outside it. You may also need to invoke the command via `cmd /c`, not just "straight up"

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the output in a variable and then after the iteration output it into a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) inside the [scriptblock of the `foreach` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6) .

```
foreach ($user in get-content file.txt) { dsget user $user -samid  >> output_file.txt }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick replies.  I used the above example and it worked fine.  I'm relatively a noob when it comes to scripting...

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe the foreach passes anything along the pipe.  You should include the output redirection inside the foreach block like:

```
foreach ($user in get-content file.txt) {dsget user $user -samid >> output_file.txt}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though it's not obvious, **your line is made up of *two separate statements*:**

- `foreach ($user in get-content file.txt) { dsget user $user -samid }`, which prints to the *console*.
- `>> output_file.txt`, which is not a valid statement by itself and causes a *syntax error*.

<sup>Given that using a simple *expression* with output redirection works fine - e.g., `'hi' > out.txt` - the question is why this isn't possible with compound *statements* such as a `foreach` loop and an `if` statement. Unfortunately, the fundamentals of PowerShell's grammar prevent that; see [GitHub issue #10967](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10967#issuecomment-561843650).</sup>

As several others have pointed out, you can move `>> output_file.txt` inside the script block - in which case the output redirection is performed in *each iteration* -  but **there *is* a solution with a *single* redirection**:

```bash
& { foreach ($user in get-content file.txt) { dsget user $user -samid } } > output_file.txt
```

**By using `& { ... }` you turn the `foreach` loop into a (streaming) *command* whose output can be redirected**.

<sup>You could also use `$(...)`, but then all output would be collected *in memory* first.</sup>

---

However, **to truly get streaming, one-by-one processing, you can use the *pipeline* with the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*** as follows - this will generally be slower, but more memory-efficient:

```bash
Get-Content file.txt | ForEach-Object { dsget user $_ -samid } > output_file.txt
```

Note how the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (whose alias, somewhat unfortunately, is also named `foreach`) has an *implicit* loop variable: the automatic `$_` variable.

Note that **`>` and `>>`** are effectively just different names for the `Out-File` cmdlet, which **produce UTF-16LE ("Unicode") files by default**, which can cause problems for others tools.
**To control the output character encoding, use `Out-File` directly**; e.g., using the example of ASCII encoding:

```bash
Get-Content file.txt | foreach { dsget user $_ -samid } | Out-File -Encoding Ascii output_file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($user in get-content file.txt) { dsget user $user -samid } | Out-File C:\output_file.txt
```

Comment: You can't use a `foreach` loop in a pipeline, unless you wrap it in `$(...)` or `& { ... }`.

Comment: I just did this with no problem at all `foreach($line in get-content .\WindowsCodecsRaw.txt){$line}`

Comment: In a pipe, `foreach` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`

Comment: Also, as written the foreach would just be a regular foreach loop since you aren't really in the pipe yet you are creating the initial stream for the pipe.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @EBGreen: Try `foreach($line in get-content file.txt){$line} > out.txt` or `foreach($line in get-content file.txt){$line} | Out-File out.txt`, and you'll see that it breaks. Yes, it is the `foreach` _loop_ statement (expression mode) we're talking about here, not the `ForEach-Object` _cmdlet_; _simple_ expressions work as-is as the first pipeline segment (only), but _compound_ statements such as loops and conditionals do not - that's when you need `& { ... }` (or `. { ... }`) - which (potentially) _stream_ - or `$(...)`, which collects all input up front.